# nodejs child_process not outputting ansi data

Tags: node.js, child-process

so I'm trying to spawn the `npm install` command with node. The code works fine but one weird thing that I noticed is that, node isn't giving me the ansi color codes and also the progress bar seen when running the command. This is how I spawned the child and collected the output:

```js
const { spawn } = require('child_process'),
    proc = spawn('npm', ['install']);

proc.stdout.setEncoding('utf8');
proc.stderr.setEncoding('utf8');

let stdout = '';
proc.stdout?.on('data', (buffer) => {
    stdout += buffer;
});

let stderr = '';
proc.stderr?.on('data', (buffer) => {
    stderr += buffer;
});

proc.on('close', (stat) => {
    console.log(stdout, stderr)
    if (stat === 0) return;
    console.log(stat);
});
```

The command's progress bar doesn't seem to be captured and same for the vulnerability numbers' colors.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using [node-pty](https://github.com/microsoft/node-pty) and it works fine. Here's my code if you want:

````js
const pty = require('node-pty'),
    proc = pty.spawn('npm', ['install'], {
        name: 'xterm-color',
        cols: 80,
        rows: 30,
        cwd: process.cwd(),
        env: process.env
    });

let out = '';

proc.onData((buffer) => out += buffer);

proc.onExit((e) => {
    console.log(out, e);
});```
````